# .html() is not working properly with fadeOut();

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this simple feature that when I click a button there will be a message that says `Success`

It is working but only on the first time when the button is clicked, when I click the button for the second time and again and again the message `Success` is not showing anymore.

Here's my jQuery/Javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var message = 'Success';

    $('#message').html(message).delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
  })
})
```

It seems that `.html(message).delay(5000).fadeOut(400);` is the suspect or am i wrong?

This is my Html code

```
<div id="message"></div>
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
```

I have js fiddle for it. Here's the link https://jsfiddle.net/2dn9p1hv/

Comment: You have to make the "message" `<div>` visible again; after it has been faded out, it stays that way.

Comment: Ohh geez thanks! It's working now I just added this line of code ```$('#message-group').html(message).fadeIn(400);```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

In your code you are using jQuery's **.fadeOut()** mathod which makes element [invisible](https://api.jquery.com/fadeout/). Unless you will explicitly make it visible it will stay that way. You can make element [visible](https://api.jquery.com/fadein/) e.g. by using related method **.fadeIn()**.

## Solution

You can use **.fadeIn()** to show invisible message as below:

```js
$('#message').html(message).fadeIn(400);
```

In your code it should be placed like below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var message = 'Success';
    $('#message').html(message).fadeIn(400);
    $('#message').html(message).delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
  })
})
```